# Avoid or mitigate race condition for two functions sharing same variable (resource) in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition, autoresetevent, waithandle

- I have two functions in different classes, and they are generating race condition.
- One function is updating variables value and another one is using variable, and they are in Race condition my assumption.
- `counter` variable is accessible from both functions.
  `var counter=0`;
- Both functions are in different classes.

**Function updating value**

```cs
protected void updateValue(SomeClassType val){
  // Based upon some condition value for variable is updated
  if(val.id){ // some condition
    counter=2;
  }
}
```

**Function using value**

```cs
protected void useValue(var counter){
  // Do something with variable.
}
```

- The `upateValue` function is running in `worker-thread`. and `useValue` is running in `main-thread`.
- What I need is `useValue` should wait till `updateValue`, updates variable value.

**What I Tried**

- Created one static object of `AutoResetEvent`.

```cs
public static AutoResetEvent autoResetEventForUpdateValue = new AutoResetEvent(false);
protected void updateValue(SomeClassType val){
  // Based upon some condition value for variable is updated
  if(val.id){ // some condition
    counter=2;
  }
  autoResetEventForUpdateValue.Set();
}
```

**Function using value**

```cs
WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[] { autoResetEventForUpdateValue};
protected void useValue(var counter){
  // Do something with variable.
}
```

> Also `updateValue(val)`, this parameter `val` of type `SomeClassType` is not accessible in implementation of class `useValue(counter)`.

- With my solution while debugging I realized that `useValue` keep waiting and `updateValue` is not initialized as `worker-thread` not running there.

Comment: Is `counter` an `int`? If so, have a look at [Interlocked.Increment()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-7.0).

Comment: `useValue(var counter)` - this is not C#. Should it be `useValue(int counter)`? "Bothe functions are in different classes." - so how do they have access to the same variable?

Comment: Re: "What I need is `useValue` should wait till `updateValue` updates variable value." Q: what does `useValue` do? Why not simply call `useValue` from the same thread that called `updateValue`? If `useValue` truly needs to run in a different thread, then why not use a thread _pool_ and have `updateValue` submit a new _task_ to the thread pool? Why not have it pass the "value" as an argument to the task instead of passing it through the shared variable?

Comment: Also `useValue(var counter)` accepts the `counter` as an argument. If it's a value type, you are getting a **copy** of the `counter`. If it's a reference type, you are getting a reference to it. Don't expect this value to change if it was updated externally

Comment: Since `counter` is a value type (in contrast to the reference type), you are passing its **copy** into `useValue` method. Don't expect it to change here. You must wait for `autoResetEventForUpdateValue` **before** calling `useValue` method, not inside. Also, you don't need to create `WaitHandle` array, just call `autoResetEventForUpdateValue.WaitOne()`.

Comment: "With my solution while debugging I realized that useValue keep waiting and updateValue is not initialized as worker-thread not running there." So there is no race condition, the code just not running? You probably should close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I would just change `UpdateValue` to return the value instead of updating it in place, that should make ordering trivial:

```
var currentCounterValue = ...
var updatedCounterValue = await Task.Run(() => ComputeNewCounterValue(currentCounterValue));
UseValue(updatedCounterValue );
```

Pure methods, i.e. methods without side effects, where the result only depend on the input, tend to be the easiest to use. This is especially true when dealing with multi threading.

You might also want some mechanism to ensure your method cannot run concurrently. If this is triggered by a button press you could disable the button before you call `ComputeNewCounterValue` and enable it after `UseValue`;

Comment: Resrticted to not return a value from ```updateCounterValue```, function. Is any other approach I can go with?

Comment: @Nikkkshit Restricted by what? You can always turn a non-returning method into one that returns a value by letting the method take a reference that it updates. Or by moving the parameters & return values into object properties. This is typically not things you should do yourself, but the compiler does a bunch of stuff like this to "lower" local functions/closures/async methods etc.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add parameter in function, that parameter are not available in the class where the function in using counter value.